# How do I fix Trying to access array offset on value of type null on a live server?

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-query-builder

Everything works on localhost but am getting error when I deploy on a live server.
Can anyone help?

**CONTROLLER**

```php
$status = Auth::guest()
    ? null
    : Request::where('person_id', auth()->user()->persn['id'])
        ->orderBy('id','DESC')
        ->limit(1)
        ->get();
```

**BLADE TEMPLATE**

```xml
@if(!empty(Auth::user()->persn->id) == !empty(Auth::user()->persn->req[0]->person_id) )
  @foreach ($status as $statu)
    @if($statu->is_accepted == 1 && $statu->is_payed == 1)
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-success mr-3" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#LoanReq">
        <i class="fas fa-paper-plane"></i> Ask
      </a>
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-warning" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#Status-modal" onclick="return update(event)">
        <i class="mdi mdi-bell"></i> Statut
      </a>
    @else
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-secondary mr-3" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#MyProfile-form">
        <i class="mdi mdi-face-outline"></i> Account
      </a>
      @if ($status[0]->is_accepted == 1 && strtotime($status[0]->count_deadline) > time())
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-success" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#Status-modal" onclick="return update(event)">
          <i class="mdi mdi-bell"></i> Statut
        </a>
      @else
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-warning" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#Status-modal" onclick="return update(event)">
          <i class="mdi mdi-bell"></i> Statut
        </a>
      @endif
    @endif
  @endforeach
@else
  <h1>NOTHING</h1>
@endif
```

Comment: Hi BMFA! can you upload screenshot of the error  you are getting in the live server?

Comment: also you are referring to a person then typing `->persn['id']` are you sure all of your code is spelt correctly.

Comment: Hi @Doro the error message is the title of my question.

Comment: Okay I get it now.....to handle this situation use the optional() to guard it... Like optional(auth()->user()->persn)['id'] . U can also apply it in blade like

Answer (score 0):

The line

```xml
@if(!empty(Auth::user()->persn->id) == !empty(Auth::user()->persn->req[0]->person_id) )
```

is the most likely culprit. More specifically

```php
!empty(Auth::user()->persn->req[0]->person_id)
                               ^^^
```

if `Auth::user()->persn->req` evaluates to `null`, then trying to get an offset of it will throw an error.

This condition is weird, but one way to ugly patch this error would be

```xml
@if ( !empty(Auth::user()->persn->id) == ( !empty(Auth::user()->persn->req) && !empty(Auth::user()->persn->req[0]->person_id) ) )
```

Also, since `empty`returns a bool, you should use logical operators.

```xml
@if (!empty(Auth::user()->persn->id
    && !empty(Auth::user()->persn->req)
    && !empty(Auth::user()->persn->req[0]->person_id))
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But the error is pointing at the controller line I posted above. The blade code works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `optional()` method to guard your relationship queries like

```
optional(auth()->user()->persn)->id
```

or

```
optional(auth()->user()->persn)['id']
```

Comment: Thanks for the time you dedicate to this problem. I fixed that error by removing the `where('person_id', auth()->user()->persn['id'])`. But am alson gonna try your method.

Comment: It's okay.... thanks 

Answer (score 0):

By checking my blade codes, I realized that I was just repeating the same condition. So I had to remove the below line from my controller to fix the error.

```
where('person_id', auth()->user()->persn['id'])
```